# DynamoDB for .net: Table name in data model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using Dynamodb.net in my application.

I have the following code.

```
var creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsId, awsPassword);
var dynamoClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds, 
awsDynamoDbRegion);
var context = new DynamoDBContext(dynamoClient);
List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
conditions.Add(new ScanCondition("Id", ScanOperator.Equal, myId));            
var response = await context.ScanAsync<Data>(conditions).GetRemainingAsync();
return response;
```

My Data Model is as:

```
[DynamoDBTable("MyTable")]
public class Data
{
     [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

We are harcoding the table table name in our model "Data" as

```
 [DynamoDBTable("MyTable")]
```

How can we not hardcode this. Is it possible to apply the table name in my actual code itself instead of giving in the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `OverrideTableName` in `DynamoDBOperationConfig` what you are looking for ?

Description:

> Property that indicates the table to save an object to overriding the
>   DynamoDBTable attribute declared for the type.

Example:

```
var x = await DbContext.LoadAsync<T>("hash", new DynamoDBOperationConfig {
    OverrideTableName = "NewTableName",
    IndexName = indexName
});
```

Also what you are looking for might be table prefix for every request of DbContext. It will append this prefix to every table. Useful if you want to isolate application specific tables like AppName-MyTable...

Example:

```
return new DynamoDBContextConfig
{
   TableNamePrefix = "MyAppIdentifier",
   ConsistentRead = false,
};
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Currently I have just one table so might not need consistentread.

Comment: I have another question, not exactly related to this. Let me know if you want me to open a new post. I have different API with different endpoints Eg for get, post, delete etc. Now since I am using dynamo db here in every api call I am creating BasicAWSCredentials, AmazonDynamoDBClient, DynamoDBContext,ScanCondition. Is it possible to create some kind of efficient  private method in my api that initializes this instead of repeating this very code. See my original post for the declaration.

Comment: Connecting with ID and Password is not suggested. Rather keep them in environment variables. If you are running this code on EC2 or on Lambda you dont need to specify credentials at all. Having this said. As to your question. Why don't you have a shared class that does the initialization job. Other than that DynamoDB requests are HTTP requests. Multiple DbContext is not a load to the system. But its recommended that with Lambda initialize connections outside of the handler so when lambda is re-used they are ready to use.

Comment: The ID, Passwords are not hardcoded. But taken from appsettings file which in turn are replaced during the deployment based on the environment. Havent worked with lambda yet.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use different prefixes for the tables via
 `Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContextConfig.TableNamePrefix`

> Property that directs DynamoDBContext to prefix all table names with a specific string. > If property is null or empty, no prefix is used and default table names are used.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDynamoDBContextConfig.html

e.g.:

```
    var credentials = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("default");
    var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    var config = new DynamoDBContextConfig{
            TableNamePrefix = "Test."
    };

    var ctx = new DynamoDBContext(client, config);

    await ctx.SaveAsync(item);
```